# Getting "You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream" while using django-rest-framework

Tags: android, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

My first question here, & a newbie to everything including coding.

I am using django-rest-framework to call a rest api from an android app I am building.

I am calling another view's method from the api_view method of django-rest-framework.

This works great with the GET method, but fails while using the POST method.

Below is the code:

View 1:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST']) 
    def get_dos(request):
        return View2.get_data(request)
```

View 2:

```
def get_data(request):
    #if I print request.body, it goes through without problems
    #print request.body 

    #but commenting it fails when I read from request.POST.get below:

    var1 = int(request.POST.get('test', 0))
    #fails in the above statement.
```

I have tried commenting all middleware classes in the settings file, but no luck :(. I keep getting "You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream" error.

Am I doing something silly? Any assistance appreciated. Thanks!